# Random.Next doesn't go up to max parameter

Tags: c#, random

Whenever my app chooses a "random" card, it always follows the same strange pattern : Clubs only 1-3, Diamonds 4-6, Hearts 7-9, Spades 10-12. The suits are always in that number range and never change. Each suite is supposed to be allowed to go to 13! Please help me solve thing perplexing problem, thanks!

Source:

```
    Random Suite = new Random();
    Random Value = new Random();
    int sprod;
    int vprod;

     public Card RandomCardDraw()
     {
        sprod = Suite.Next(1, 5);

        Card newc = new Card();

        newc.x = sprod;

        vprod = Value.Next(1, 13);

        if (sprod == 1)
        {
            newc.suite = CardSuites.Club;

            newc.y = vprod;

            switch (vprod)
            {
                case 1:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Ace;
                    return newc;
                case 2:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Two;
                    return newc;
                case 3:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Three;
                    return newc;
                case 4:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Four;
                    return newc;
                case 5:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Five;
                    return newc;
                case 6:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Six;
                    return newc;
                case 7:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Seven;
                    return newc;
                case 8:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Eight;
                    return newc;
                case 9:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Nine;
                    return newc;
                case 10:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Ten;
                    return newc;
                case 11:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Jack;
                    return newc;
                case 12:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Queen;
                    return newc;
                case 13:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.King;
                    return newc;
            }
        }
        if (sprod == 2)
        {
            newc.suite = CardSuites.Diamond;

            newc.y = vprod;

            switch (vprod)
            {
                case 1:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Ace;
                    return newc;
                case 2:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Two;
                    return newc;
                case 3:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Three;
                    return newc;
                case 4:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Four;
                    return newc;
                case 5:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Five;
                    return newc;
                case 6:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Six;
                    return newc;
                case 7:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Seven;
                    return newc;
                case 8:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Eight;
                    return newc;
                case 9:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Nine;
                    return newc;
                case 10:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Ten;
                    return newc;
                case 11:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Jack;
                    return newc;
                case 12:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Queen;
                    return newc;
                case 13:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.King;
                    return newc;
            }
        }
        if (sprod == 3)
        {
            newc.suite = CardSuites.Heart;

            newc.y = vprod;

            switch (vprod)
            {
                case 1:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Ace;
                    return newc;
                case 2:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Two;
                    return newc;
                case 3:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Three;
                    return newc;
                case 4:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Four;
                    return newc;
                case 5:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Five;
                    return newc;
                case 6:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Six;
                    return newc;
                case 7:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Seven;
                    return newc;
                case 8:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Eight;
                    return newc;
                case 9:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Nine;
                    return newc;
                case 10:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Ten;
                    return newc;
                case 11:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Jack;
                    return newc;
                case 12:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Queen;
                    return newc;
                case 13:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.King;
                    return newc;
            }
        }
        if (sprod == 4)
        {
            newc.suite = CardSuites.Spade;

            newc.y = vprod;

            switch (vprod)
            {
                case 1:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Ace;
                    return newc;
                case 2:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Two;
                    return newc;
                case 3:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Three;
                    return newc;
                case 4:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Four;
                    return newc;
                case 5:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Five;
                    return newc;
                case 6:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Six;
                    return newc;
                case 7:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Seven;
                    return newc;
                case 8:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Eight;
                    return newc;
                case 9:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Nine;
                    return newc;
                case 10:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Ten;
                    return newc;
                case 11:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Jack;
                    return newc;
                case 12:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.Queen;
                    return newc;
                case 13:
                    newc.cardval = CardValues.King;
                    return newc;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return newc;
        }
        return newc;
    }
```

Comment: What would you do if a deck had 1000 cards?

Comment: This is in the very early development stages, I'm planning on implementing a more elegant system later :)

Comment: RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx Next() has an _exclusive_ upper bound, which means that if you want a number from 1 to 4, you call Next(1, 5).

Comment: I apologize for the sloppiness, as you can see I began to fix all that at the top and then got distracted by the more pressing issue. (BTW, why the down-votes?)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker He's not asking about why the upper bound isn't included, he's asking why they always end up in the same ranges. It's bc he has the `Random` instances initialized with the same seed.

Comment: Do you recommend making a seperate random for each suite?

Comment: Yes, there are more problems; he gets (1, 5) right, but then the (1, 13) is wrong. Yes, he's not seeding the RNG properly. And of course the big problem is that what he's doing should be 5 lines of code, not 100. And a big peeve of mine: There's no E in SUIT !

Comment: And even after the two-random class problem is solved, it can still produce the same card which is not correct logically. I think it is time to start to *`implement a more elegant system`* **now**.

Comment: I am still very new to C#, go easy on me guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a slight variation on the problem that many people have with `Random`. The default constructor is initialized with a seed that is based on `Environment.TickCount`. If you create two instances quickly they will end up with the same seed because the system timer has not updated. Thus both instances produce the same sequence of numbers. `Next(int,int)` does some simple scaling of a double that is generated by the protected `Sample` method. Just use a single random instance and call `Next(1,5)` or `Next(1,13)`.

Comment: @user2649633 and it should actually be `Next(1, 14)` to get a range 1 - 13

Answer (score 0):

If `CardValues` and `CardSuites` are enums, all that code can be effectively replaced with

```
static Random random = new Random();

static Card RandomCardDraw()
{
    var suite = random.Next(5);
    var value = random.Next(14);
    return Card
    {
            x = suite + 1,
            y = value + 1,
            suite   = (CardSuites)suite,
            cardval = (CardValues)value,
    };
}
```

Notes:

You need only one `Random` instance. Two instances created at the same time will have the same seed and produce correlating sequences (or identical sequences if provided with the same parameters).

Last parameter of `Random.Next()` is *exclusive*.

Comment: Good suggestion, I am very new to programming so I do not fully understand the presented concept but it is much better than my cumbersome 200+ lines of code! Thanks!

Comment: Corrected to random.Next(5) and random.Next(14).  When using single parameter, Max Value is ALSO exclusive.

Comment: In fact you don't need two `Next` as well. `var rCard = random.Next(52); int suite = rCard / 13; int cardVal = rCard % 13;`